# Configure Docker credential store for Spring Boot native image build during CI/CD

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I would like to build a Spring Boot 3 native image and push it to Docker Hub, with the help of Docker credential store.

I am using this piece of code in my GitLab pipeline (same would apply with any other CI/CD):

```yaml
build:
  image: vegardit/graalvm-maven:21.0.1
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn spring-boot:build-image
    - echo somepassword | docker login -u myuser --password-stdin somedockerhub:443
    - docker push somedockerhub:443/path/whatjustgotbuilt:latest
```

As you can see, I am using a build container, here `vegardit/graalvm-maven:21.0.1`.

First, I run the `spring-boot` command which will build the image. The image is there.
Second, I log in to Docker Hub in step 2. As you can see, I am already using the construct `cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin` suggested from the doc.
Three, I push the image built in step 1.

While this is successful, I am always getting this warning:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

From the guide, it seems I need to use this:

```
{
  "credsStore": "???"
}
```

But what would be the value of `credsStore` for my `vegardit/graalvm-maven:21.0.1` build image?

How do I pass this file to `vegardit/graalvm-maven:21.0.1`?